# Is it possible to translate the name of a field in the CP?

Tags: localization, fieldtypes

I have content editors that speaks different languages. Is there a way to translate the name and introduction of a field in the control panel? A simple {{ "value"|t }} seams not to work.

Example: English content editors should see "surname" as field name and german speaking editors should see "Nachname".

[image: Field configuration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static text on the front-end and Craft CP translations are handled through your [translation files](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations).

All you need to do is name your fields without the translate filter and make sure they have suitable translation arrays in your translation files.

It's also worth mentioning you will need [Craft Pro](http://buildwithcraft.com/pricing) to take advantage of localisation and translation features.

Here is an example to get you started, this will be added to the translation file for your German locale:

```
<?php

return array(
    'Surname' => 'Nachname',
);
```

Comment: Great! I tryed only to use translations with the filter. Now, without the filter it works as expected!